# Error while parsing POM

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, browserstack

I am trying to integrate Browserstack with jenkins, using maven to build java code for testing.

However when I run the Job I got this errors and pretty much crashes the build and next steps.

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:jar:1.8 is   invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
```

that leads to the next errors what I think are related:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.browserstack:automate-maven-plugin:0.7.2-SNAPSHOT:test-compile (default) on project NewTest: Execution default of goal com.browserstack:automate-maven-plugin:0.7.2-SNAPSHOT:test-compile failed: A required class was missing while executing com.browserstack:automate-maven-plugin:0.7.2-SNAPSHOT:test-compile: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>com.browserstack:automate-maven-plugin:0.7.2-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testbrowserstack/.repository/com/browserstack/automate-maven-plugin/0.7.2-SNAPSHOT/automate-maven-plugin-0.7.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testbrowserstack/.repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testbrowserstack/.repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testbrowserstack/.repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.7/aether-util-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testbrowserstack/.repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testbrowserstack/.repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testbrowserstack/.repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testbrowserstack/.repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testbrowserstack/.repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.24/plexus-utils-3.0.24.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testbrowserstack/.repository/org/codehaus/mojo/aspectj-maven-plugin/1.8/aspectj-maven-plugin-1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testbrowserstack/.repository/org/aspectj/aspectjtools/1.8.7/aspectjtools-1.8.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testbrowserstack/.repository/com/browserstack/automate-testassist/0.7.2-SNAPSHOT/automate-testassist-0.7.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Here is my pom file which also uses the right version of the openjdk:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>NewTest</groupId>
  <artifactId>NewTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-Unittest</version>
    <dependencies>      
    <!--
    <dependency>                
         <groupId>junit</groupId>                               
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>                             
         <version>3.8.1</version>                               
         <scope>test</scope>                                
    </dependency>               
    <dependency>                
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>                              
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>                              
        <version>2.45.0</version>                               
        </dependency>               
    <dependency>                
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>                               
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>                             
        <version>6.8</version>                              
        <scope>test</scope>                                     
       </dependency>
      -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.browserstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>automate-testassist</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
   <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
    <groupId>com.browserstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>automate-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>test-compile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>



</project>
```

No sure what would be the issue.

Comment: Based on the message I assume your Jenkins is not allowed to download all needed files...You should check the whole log file on errors WARNINGS etc...

Comment: So far i am realizing that the problem could be dependencies in automate-maven-plugin, I triend aspectj-maven-plugin:jar:1.9 standalone and it worked, and at the same time automate-maven-plugin failed looking for version 1.8

Answer (score 1):

The culprit here is `automate-maven-plugin` used by you. The error message as well clearly reads this

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.browserstack:automate-maven-plugin:0.7.2-SNAPSHOT:test-compile
>   (default) on project NewTest: Execution default of goal
>   com.browserstack:automate-maven-plugin:0.7.2-SNAPSHOT:test-compile
>   failed: A required class was missing while executing
>   com.browserstack:automate-maven-plugin:0.7.2-SNAPSHOT:test-compile:
>   org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils

Also trying to use the `0.7.2-SNAPSHOT` of `automate-maven-plugin` along with specifying the same `pluginRepositories` wouldn't work in general. Seems like you are locally building and using this. So probably you can go ahead and update the plugin possibly.

Comment: I am waiting to see if there is a kind of bug with outdated libraries, from browserstack, not sure if I can manually specify a aspectj-maven-plugin version.

Comment: @YerisAntonio You need to contact the library owners to get the bug fixed. Probably using `aspectj-maven-plugin` is a call you shall take depending on your requirements which I doubt are listed above.